# Kotlin: Hashmap of interface methods by the implementing class name

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a list of clases that implement a specific interface. The ability to construct those clases or not is not static (so it's not possible to use `when(className)`), and can be configured so I want to be able to create some clases or call some methods based on a hashMap of allowed "constructors". Then if the key identifying a class is in present in the hashmap I can call the corresponding method, otherwise I can safely ignore. Let me illustrate:

Let's say I have an interface like

```
interface Instanceable {

    data class Config(
        val bar: Whatever
    )

    fun getIntance(config: Config): Instanceable
}
```

Then I have several (let's say 10) classes that implement this interface

```
class Implementation1() : Instanceable {

    companion object {
        const val ID = "INSTANCE_1"
    }

    private lateinit var foo: Whatever

    override fun getIntance(config: Config) = Implementation1().also{ this@Implementation1.foo = config.bar }

}
```

I want to create a hashmap of the methods by the identifiers, so later down the lane I can grab the method from the hashMap by the key ID and just `invoke()` the value if it's there. Something like:

```
allowedInstances("INSTANCE_1")?.let{ it.invoke(someConfig) }
```

In order to do this I tried to create a hashMap of methods like this:

```
private val allowedInstances = mutableHashMapOf<String, Instanceable.(Instanceable.Config)->Instanceable>()    
allowedInstances[Instance1.ID] = Instance1::getIntance
allowedInstances[Instance2.ID] = Instance2::getIntance
allowedInstances[Instance4.ID] = Instance4::getIntance
```

But it fails with:

```
Type mismatch.
    Required: Instanceable.(Instanceable.Config) → Instanceable
    Found: KFunction2<Implementation1, Instanceable.Config, Instanceable>
```

If I create the hashmap directly and let the compiler infer the types like this:

```
private val allowedInstances = mutableHashMapOf(
    Implementation1.ID to Implementation1::getIntance,
    Implementation2.ID to Implementation2::getIntance,
    Implementation4.ID to Implementation4::getIntance,
)
```

Checking the type of the hashmap shows:

```
HashMap<String, out KFunction2<Nothing, Instanceable.Config, Instanceable>>
```

In fact I can do:

```
private val allowedInstances = mutableHashMapOf<String, Nothing.(Instanceable.Config)->Instanceable>()
allowedInstances[Instance1.ID] = Instance1::getIntance
allowedInstances[Instance2.ID] = Instance2::getIntance
allowedInstances[Instance4.ID] = Instance4::getIntance
```

So the actual question is:

**Why the function of the second hashMap parameter has Nothing as the receptor? Why I cannot have the interface Instanceable instead?**

---

Edit: Still not good to have the `Nothing` there:

```
allowedInstances["INSTANCE_1"]?.let{ it.invoke(Nothing, someConfig) }
//Fails with: Classifier 'Nothing' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

---

Edit 2: All of the errors are in compile time

Answer (score 1):

Your function type

```
Instanceable.(Instanceable.Config) -> Instanceable
```

is describing an extension function on an instance of Instanceable. You need to omit the receiver from the function type to be able to match your constructors' signature:

```
(Instanceable.Config) -> Instanceable
```

---

Edit: The other half of the problem is that you define `getInstance()` as a member function of the class. So you have to create an invalid instance of your class to use to create a valid instance, which doesn't make sense.

I would delete the `getInstance()` function from your interface, and put the equivalent code in the constructor of your class. Then you can define a function type in your Map that constructs your items.

```
interface Instanceable {

    data class Config(
        val bar: Whatever
    )

    // REMOVE this: fun getIntance(config: Config): Instanceable
}

class Implementation1(config: Config) : Instanceable {

    companion object {
        const val ID = "INSTANCE_1"
    }

    private val foo: Whatever = config.bar

}

private val allowedInstances = mutableHashMapOf<String, (Instanceable.Config)->Instanceable>()    
allowedInstances[Instance1.ID] = ::Implementation1
// and so on...

// If there's an implementation that has no config, you can use a lambda:
class NoConfigImplementation : Instanceable {

    companion object {
        const val ID = "INSTANCE_2"
    }
}

allowedInstances[NoConfigImplementation.ID] = { _ -> NoConfigImplementation() }
```

Comment: If I omit the receiver I get the following error: `Type mismatch.
Required:
(Instanceable.Config) → Instanceable
Found:
KFunction2<Instance1, Instanceable.Config, Instanceable>`.
One error on each line I add an entry on the hashmap

Comment: Oh, I didn’t notice the weird setup you have there. `getInstance()` is a member function of your implementation classes, which doesn’t make sense. You have to create an invalid instance to use to get a valid instance. There’s no way to do this in a type-enforceable way. There is no type restriction on available constructors.

Comment: Where should I place the getInstance()

Comment: I would remove the function from the interface and set the config in the constructor of each implementation. Pass the constructors as the values in your map. Delete `getInstance()` from the interface definition. You can't enforce constructors with an interface. See updated answer.

Comment: It is a weird setup indeed, the implementations can behave as as a class instance when injected or as a factory of themselves when invoking `getInstance`. I can't pass the config with the default constructor, the classes are injected elsewhere and I don't have the config at injection time. I guess the answer is to change this to a factory pattern instead of whatever this is.  Also thanks for your answer, it really helped. I was looking for the answer of why in this scenario the compiler suggests `Nothing` (and it compiles!) but it really does not make sense to have this scenario to being with.

Comment: I can explain the Nothing thing. Nothing is logically the subtype of everything, so you can use it in type definitions as an input argument for anything. But then in practice you can't actually create a Nothing to use. You were combining functions with different inputs into the same collection, so the common input type is the common subtype Nothing. Since you can't create a Nothing, there's no way to pull one of these functions out of your map and invoke it, because you won't know which class to instantiate and pass as the receiver.